# Symfony 1.4: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am trying to rebuild a symfony 1.4 database by running the following command:

`./symfony propel:build-sql`

When I run the command, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 89 bytes) in
>   /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.4.19/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel-generator/classes/propel/engine/database/model/Table.php
>   on line 554

I checked `my memory_limit` configuration in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

The line is as follows:

`memory_limit = -1`

Which specifies no limit on memory, so I don't understand what is causing the error, as there is no restriction on memory. What could be causing this?

Comment: Try setting the memory_limit to 1024MB, see if that works.

Comment: @craig1231: I tried your suggestion, now when I run the command, i GET: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
Could not startup.`

Comment: Yup that seems to have done the trick! Do you want to submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the memory_limit to something like "1024M"?