# How can I increase the allowed memory size in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, memory, error-handling

I try to install a package in Symfony 4 and I get an error message:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug                       
!!   // true                                                                        
!!  
!!  
!!  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/coding/myproject/vendor/twig/twig/src/Node/Expression/NameExpression.php on line 27
!!  
!!  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /Users/coding/myproject/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Data.php on line 321
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I tried to increase the memorey limit by updating my php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

But still I get the same error message

Comment: Did you check with a `phpinfo` that when you set `memory_limit` it actually worked?

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file? There usually is one for CLI and one for webservers

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Yes, I checked php info, it is correctly 2048M

Comment: What actually solved the problem is, I was searching for the php.ini via `php --ini` and this file I changed. And it worked then

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, it's an actual problem. The key is the @auto-scripts in the last line, this is something in composer.json that runs the command but you can't add parameters to increase the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/console [your command]`

Comment: tested it but the message is: Could not open input file: bin/console

Comment: depends in which directory you are - the answer is correct.